# How to get data from psql using cmd via ssh Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssh, psql

i want to get data in database psql from my computer local vi ssh ruby. But my program not finish and print output

```
$messageid = 'xxx'
$table_data_base = 'yyy'
 ...........    
Net::SSH.start($host, $user_name, :password => $pass_word) do |ssh|
  ssh.exec!("PGPASSWORD='pass' psql -d data_base_name -U user_name")
  data_mail = ssh.exec!("SELECT * FROM #{$table_data_base} WHERE messageid=#{$messageid};")
end
puts data_mail
```

Comment: Why not use a database driver instead? Ruby has "pg" https://deveiate.org/code/pg/ It should do everything you need.

Comment: I have using 'pg' to do this success but my teacher don't want to  use 'pg' and said only use cmd via ssh

Answer (score 0):

I just find answer of my question: it similar using cmd ssh to get data:

```
 cmd1 = "PGPASSWORD='pass' psql -d data_base_name -U user_name"
 cmd2 = "\\\"SELECT * FROM #{$table_data_base} WHERE messageid=#{$messageid};\\\""
 Net::SSH.start($host, $user_name, :password => $pass_word) do |ssh|
   data_mail = ssh.exec!("#{cmd1} -c #{cmd2}")
 end
```

or we use simple cmd ssh to connect and get data

`data_mail = %x[ssh #{cmd1} -c #{cmd2}]`